# Debug React Native APIs from chrome dev console

Tags: react-native, google-chrome-devtools

I'm wondering if it's possible to to test React Native APIs (e.g. `PixelRatio.get()`) in the chrome developer console.  When I tried this I got an error claiming "PixelRatio is not defined".  However, if I set a variable (e.g. `const pixelRatio = PixelRatio.get()`) the value is returned fine (see screenshot below)

Why isn't PixelRatio defined when I try to call methods on it in the chrome dev console?
[image]

Comment: set variable to PixelRatio

Comment: @Brunaine That worked, thanks.  Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: sure i will write it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the variable to `PixelRatio` and it should work, case sensitive.